# knockout array binding not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

`monkeyStuff` does what i want, it updates the span content if i write in the input field.
But why doesn't it work with the `voteStuff`?

See it in Action: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/he2zoa3d/1/)**

```
<body>
    <div id="monkeyStuff">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:monkey" />
        <span data-bind="text:monkey"></span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="voteStuff">
        <div data-bind="text: test"></div>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: voters">
          <li>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:name" />
            <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>        
        var vm = {
            monkey: ko.observable()
        };
        vm.monkey("Quak");
        ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('monkeyStuff'));

        var model = {
            test: 'Test address text',
            voters: ko.observableArray([
                { name: 'First Voter' },
                { name: 'Second Voter' }
            ])
        };

        ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById('voteStuff') );

    </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT:** OK it works like this:

```
  voters: ko.observableArray([
        { name: ko.observable('First Voter') },
        { name: ko.observable('Second Voter') }
    ])
```

**But** is there a way to do it automatic for each property in the voters array?

Comment: if the only action you're going to do on the observable array is adding/removing items, then making the  `name` property an observable is not needed ( it is only needed if the voter name will change later ), otherwise, if you want to automatically convert all objects before pushing them into your observableArray, then you can use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `name` property of the elements in your `voters` `ko.observableArray` also observable, which would thus allow you to alter these properties with the bindings you have implemented:

```
    voters: ko.observableArray([
        { name: ko.observable('First Voter') },
        { name: ko.observable('Second Voter') }
    ])
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/he2zoa3d/2/

Comment: you're working example doesn't work =) but i got it.

Comment: but this voter array is only for testing, what if i get a big array. is there a way to do this automatic for each property?

Comment: Sorry about the link issue, I was unsure how to update your code and then share a new link to the updated code. Nonetheless, it's fixed in my answer above.

Comment: You should create some JavaScript object ```Voter``` that has an ```observable``` data member ```name```. Then, you can even expand your ```Voter``` class later-on to add functionality!

Comment: But i get this array from json through breezejs and in the array there is a name, no, address and 30 more.. and then i only have the customer view.. so isn't there a simpler way? maybe a for each function to observer each property in the array..?

Comment: What I'm saying is to create some notion of a ```Voter``` object, so that your ```voters``` observable array would be something like: ```voters: ko.observableArrray([voter1, voter2])```. When you're parsing your JSON, you should just initialize fields of your ```Voter``` objects as you come across them.